# Simba ODBC driver for Google BigQuery doesn't see shared dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

I have Simba ODBC Driver for Google BigQuery v2.2.3 installed and I have Shared Dataset, I be able to use this shared dataset from BigQuery Web interface but can't reach it through Simba ODBC. In ODBC setting dropdown I see only my own dataset. But if I paste project name of Shared dataset in that dropdown than ODBC returns list of share datasets but not allow to test or save connection. How can I setup connection to a shared dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue could be in the account that was granted permissions to access the shared dataset is not explicitely used in the driver. Let's suppose that the *User1* was given such permission. So, in your driver configuration, especially in the connection string, you should be sure you are using the same *User1*, since connecting with a *User2* the driver will list the datasets *User1* has access to (not *User2*).

As you are not getting a conetion error and the driver is not retrieving the desired dataset, you can double-check the [Simba authehtication configuration](https://www.simba.com/products/BigQuery/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/mac/content/odbc/bq/strings.htm) and following steps depending on if you are using  User Account or Service Account.